# Can the ScalaTest checkbox function accept a CSS selector?

Tags: scala, selenium, scalatest

I’m using ScalaTest to write Selenium acceptance tests for a Play web app. I have a checkbox I want to check, using [the `checkbox` function](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium):

```
checkbox("cbx1").select()
```

As far as I can tell, it takes the `name` attribute of the `<input>` element to identify which checkbox I’m referring to. However, this checkbox is one of eight, and its name attribute is in the form `fieldname[7]`. I don’t have access to its index in my test, so I can’t generate the right name attribute value.

Is there a way to use the checkbox function with a CSS selector to identify which checkbox should be selected? I’ve tried passing a CSS selector straight to the function:

```
checkbox("""[name=^"fieldname"][value="TheCheckboxValue"]""").select()
```

But unsurprisingly, I get an error:

```
WebElement '[name^="fieldname"][value="TheCheckboxValue"]' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha — this seems to work:

```
checkbox(cssSelector("""[name=^"fieldname"][value="TheCheckboxValue"]""")).select()
```